# sweetalert2 regresar a caja de texto

Tags: ajax, sweetalert2

Hola buen día tengo un formulario de consulta que cuando no ingresa o selecciona algún select muestra mensaje atravez de la libreria sweetalert2 pero no me funciona al al hacer clic en aceptar que regrese al mismo campo validado atras del sweetalert2. Espero su gran ayuda.

```
if(document.getElementById("inputSelect").selectedIndex ==0) { 
        swal.fire({
            title: "Seleccione tipo de búsqueda", 
            confirmButtonText: "Aceptar",
        });
        inputSelect.focus();
        return false ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola bueno no encontré solución con el swal.fire tuve que utilizar otra librería no si es mas antigua.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert@2.1.2/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

```
if($("#nombres").val() == ""){
swal({
        icon: 'info',
        text: 'Ingrese sus Nombres.',
        closeModal: false
        }).then(function() {
        swal.close();
        $('#nombres').focus();
}); 
return false;
```

Asi pude resolver para regresar al formulario atras del sweetalert y posicionar el cursor en el imput.

Si hay alguien que sepa con el SWAL.FIRE dejé la respuesta por favor.